# What is HttpContext.SignInAsync() signing in against?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-identity

What does HttpContext.SignInAsync() do? I call it, but nothing gets changed in my httpcontext. When I get a new request from a user with a cookie it still has anonymous user. I'm not sure if anything is failing or how to check.

This is how I'm currently setting the user cookie and calling HttpContext.SignInAsync()

```
        private async void AddUserCookie(AuthRequest authRequest)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, authRequest.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, authRequest.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "TestClaim@Test.com")
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                IsPersistent = true,
                IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            };

            await this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I would just like some clarification on what is happening behind the scenes. I tried looking through the source code, but it didn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Have you [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) the documents?

Comment: I've read them, but I don't understand what I'm reading/I don't know what I don't know if that makes sense. I give it the httpcontext and the principal that I want to sign in. Afterwards it goes into my startup.cs and applies these options:
`
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
   {                   
   options.Cookie.Name = "MyService.Identity";
   options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
});
`
Then it returns void.

Answer (score 0):

in stratup.configure check

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```